# installing tomcat 9 on WSL

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tomcat9

After installing tomcat 9 on WSL, it isn't recognized by system.

Since systemctl command doesn't work on WSL, I used below command:

```
sudo service tomcat9 start
```

returning

```
tomcat9: unrecognized service
```

I followed 2 ways to install, but the same problem occurred.

References are:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-tomcat-9-ubuntu-1804

https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-tomcat-installation

Is there any clue for this problem?

Here is my environment:

windows 10 version 2004

ubuntu 20.04 (WSL)

openjdk version: "1.8.0_265"

**update:**

I did same process on gcp vm instance on which ubuntu 20.04 is installed to investigate the problem, and found the process has no problem on ubuntu 20.04, not on WSL.

So I assume that this problem is derived from WSL.

Logging all my process expecting someone to find a solution to install tomcat 9 on WSL-ubuntu.

**java install**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

set JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin"

source /etc/environment
```

**tomcat 9 install**

```
sudo apt install tomcat9 tomcat9-admin
```

check whether port 8080 is open (positive)

```
ss -ltn
```

check whether service command works (positive)

```
sudo service tomcat9 stop
sudo service tomcat9 start
```

Comment: Try starting Tomcat from command line, it may indicate the problem. Ensure catalina.sh is on path (manually to tomcat/bin), set JAVA_HOME (set it manually) to the jdk installation root. Check java -version to ensure path setting for JDK to jdk/din directory. Start Tomcat cataline.sh run. This may indicate what the issue is, give it a shot.

Comment: I think you should go to the tomcat install directory to start it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the tomcat9 package is broken.

To use tomcat9 on your WSL you may either :

- download tomcat9 and install it by yourself
- try to repair the broken install

Here is what I did to repair the install on my computer :

- Download a zip version of tomcat 9 from https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi
- in windows explorer open the folder \wsl$\Ubuntu\usr\share\tomcat9
- In order to repair tomcat I copied all the missing folders from the zip to the wsl installation : conf, webapps and work
- I also had to create the folder for the logs /usr/share/tomcat9/logs (you can either create it from linux shell or from windows explorer in \wsl$\Ubuntu)
- Then I could start tomcat with `sudo /usr/share/tomcat9/bin/startup.sh` and get the logs in /usr/share/tomcat9/logs/catalina.out

Comment: Wow thanks! worked exactly as specified. 
One thing to note to others who may stumble upon here, guides usually say to open up 127.0.0.1:8080 to see tomcat running. For me, this didnt work but it was served instead on localhost:8080 which led me to find out that there indeed is a difference :")

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by following steps:

1. enable systemd, see [WSL 2 - Enabling systemd](https://gist.github.com/djfdyuruiry/6720faa3f9fc59bfdf6284ee1f41f950)
2. restart WSL Ubuntu, with cmd `wsl --shutdown` and `wsl -d Ubuntu genie -s`
3. reinstall tomcat9, with shell `apt-get remove tomcat9` and `apt-get install tomcat9`

then type `service tomcat9 status`, see how things work in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

shockingly, there is no `service tomcat9 status` on my machine after install the tomcat9-admin. But if I created /usr/share/tomcat9/log directory using sudo, I could then start tomcat9 using /usr/share/tomcat9/bin/startup.sh. I also had to run before this an unmask command:

```
sudo apt install systemctl
sudo systemctl unmask tomcat9
sudo mkdir /usr/share/tomcat9/log
sudo /usr/share/tomcat9/bin/startup.sh
```

this is still highly irregular. I think it might be to do with how WSL is handling ports because mariadb and apache2 don't suffer from the same issues (out of the box).

Answer (score 0):

You have to start up tomcat manually, or write a service script to start/stop it. To manually start it set JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE then run catalina.sh.

install java and tomcat9 through apt

```
apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jre-headless
apt-get install -y tomcat9
```

then

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
export CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat9
/usr/share/tomcat9/bin/catalina.sh run
```